# Centre a div within a div with leading and trailing divs

Tags: html, css

I want to centre the middle yellow div within the blue container div, regardless of the size of the text/div on the left and right side. The size of the centre div should auto-adjust to fit the text as it will be dynamically updated.

The left side yellow div should then fill the remaining gap on the left side with right aligned text, any extra text on the left side of this div should be hidden beyond the edge of the blue container on the left.

[image: Example of desired design]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should check out flexboxes. Here is a good guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Something like this should do the trick:

```
.container{
    padding:5px;
    background:blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center
}
```

See it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/kzj983h2/3/

Comment: That's great, is there a way that it can be done without needing to fix the width of the left and right divs, so that the centre div can dynamically resize to fit the text, and then the left and right div resize to fit the remaining gap? I updated the question, as the original question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I updated the Fiddle for you. You just need to set `flex:1` to every element that should stretch.

Comment: For anyone else who is trying to do this, the final solution included adding a direction reversal on the left side to make the right align and overflow work correctly. I have created a new fiddle to show this: https://jsfiddle.net/3c8uvhm3/

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at [flexboxes](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties). I made a quick example with what you were talking about. It should work with what you need..

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('.two').text($('.two').text() + ', and more words');
});
```

```css
#content {
  display:flex;
  background:black;
  width:500px;
  padding:3px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-shrink:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.one, .two, .three {
  background:white;
  padding:3px;
}

.one, .three {
  width:10%;
}

.two {
  width:80%;
  margin: 0 3px;
}


#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
  <div class="one">Block one</div>
  <div class="two">Another word</div>
  <div class="three">Block three</div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
</div>
```